# Cron does not work well

Tags: 18.04, cron, startup

I have a bash script to use it for my tablet. There is:

```
#!/bin/bash
xinput set-prop "XP-PEN G430S Pen Pen (0)" --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 1.155756, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.529, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
```

I did `crontab -e` and added a line like that `@reboot ~/tablet.sh` Service is working but it does not start bash script.

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify a `DISPLAY` variable:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 30
export DISPLAY=:0
xinput set-prop "XP-PEN G430S Pen Pen (0)" --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 1.155756, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.529, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
echo "xinput command execution for $DISPLAY" | logger
```

Use `$ echo $DISPLAY` to find out what it is in your case.

After reboot you could check if your command have been executed:

```
$ journalctl -b | grep xinput | grep execution
```

If cron runs your script too early, you could add `sleep 30` before `xinput` command to wait 20 seconds when your desktop environment would probably be loaded or create the next systemd service:

- Create the new systemd `tabletd.service`:

  ```
  sudo vim.tiny /lib/systemd/system/tabletd.service
  sudo ln -s /lib/systemd/system/tabletd.service /etc/systemd/system/
  ```

  Paste the next to it:

  ```
  [Unit]
  Description=Start tablet service
  After=multi-user.target

  [Service]
  Type=simple
  User=<youruser>
  ExecStart=/home/<youruser>/scripts/tablet.sh
  RestartSec=10s
  Restart=on-failure

  [Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
  ```
- Enable and start the newly created service:

  ```
  sudo systemctl enable tabletd && sudo systemctl start tabletd
  ```

Comment: May 15 00:56:30 myusername [902]: xinput command execution for echo :0 It gave this output but didn't execute.

Comment: It means your script have been executed, but xinput command have not been executed. Maybe you need to create a systemd service and start it after graphical target instead of using cron. You know approximate time you could read your journal and see what happened with your xinput command: `journalctl -b > bootlog.txt`. And use gedit or other text viewer/editor to navigate to it and look what is there.

Comment: I did everything as you say but I guess I did a mistake when I did service tablet status. "May 15 01:43:00 myusername bash[804]: Unable to connect to X server
"

Comment: Have you tried to `sudo systemctl restart tablet` after user have been logged in into its desktop environment? Also open another terminal tab or window to see what `journalctl -f` displays

Comment: I did but it's still don't work, I guess I have to  do it manually way. Thank you :)

Comment: Ok. It is just interesting if it says the same or maybe something else. Have you tried to see what happens on `journalctl -f` in case of `tablet` service restarting?